# Управление программно созданными элементами

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте, скажите плиз как можно управлять элементами (UILabel, UIView, etc.) которые были созданы программно?

Допустим есть кнопка TestButton которая была создана напрямую в коде:

**.m файл:**

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
UIButton *TestButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
TestButton.title = @"Название Кнопки";
//в этом методе кнопка полностью настраивается
}

-(void) anotherMethod {
TestButton.title установить нельзя, кнопка для этого метода не видна
}
```

Как получить возможность редактировать кнопку во всех методах?
Создавать ее через IB нельзя

Comment: пробовал в .h файл добавлять

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UBOutlet UIButton TestButton

но результата не принесло

Comment: Документацию читали? По классу UIButton?

Comment: Вопрос по всем элементам. Пример написан для кнопки, но суть не в этом. Документацию читал.

Comment: Значит либо плохо читали, либо первое. И читать тогда надо по всем элементам.
Что касается кнопки, то там как то так меняется текст:

     [TestButton setTitle:@"Название Кнопки" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы кнопку объявили локальной переменной, а не переменной инстанса!

```
    @implementation UIViewController
    {
        UIButton *button;
    }

    -(void) viewDidLoad {
     button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
     button.title = @"Название Кнопки";
    }
    -(void) anotherMethod {
      button.title;
    }
```

Comment: вот-вот!:) теперь покажите где прописываются "переменные инстанса"?)

Comment: .  апдейтнул

Comment: То что надо, спасибо!